# Display attached images as background-image css

Tags: images

I have an issue here and i hope you guys help me because i'm getting crazy. Anyway, as you know wordpress output the attached images in  tag. I need them as background-image css. Here's my code;

```
        <?php
            $content = get_the_content();
            $feat_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url(  $post->ID, '' )[0];
            $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "<div class='single-
            parallax-image' style='background-image:url(".$feat_image_url.")'></div>", $content);          
            $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
            $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
            echo $content; 
        ?>
```

As you can see i need to preg_replace img tag with

```
<div class='single-parallax-image' style='background-image:url(".$feat_image_url.")'></div>
```

Thanks..

Comment: I would look for an simpler implementation like maybe using a shortcode. If you like the simplicity of adding an image through the add media interface you could hack the gallery shortcode of wordpress(if you do not plan to use it elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

using this code

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
      <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>
    <div class='single-parallax-image' style='background-image:url("<?=$image[0]; ?>")'><?=get_the_content()?></div>

      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Never use `<?=` shorthand tags as they are more than likely disabled on the hosting. Also, it is contrary to [WordPress Coding Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#no-shorthand-php-tags).

Comment: if you php version long to php5.6 you can using shorthand codes

Comment: and/or equal php5.6 version

Comment: thanks for answer but i dont want to get the post thumbnail. See, that's the problem. i want to get attached images in the post as background-image css not in <img /> tag